# is this redundant data in this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to ask if a table with data like this is redundant? If not redundant, how to make not redundant?? sory for bad english.

```
id_tunjungan    jenis_tunjangan   besar_tunjangan

BR001   beras   250000
KAM001  jabatan 100000
KAM002  kesehatan   80000
KR001   jabatan 75000
KR002   kesehatan   75000
MT001   kesehatan   50000
MT002   beras   200000
PA001   jabatan 400000
PA002   kesehatan   150000
SA001   kesehatan   75000
```

Comment: Obviously, it is redundant (the second column values are repeated).  Whether that is a problem that needs to be fixed depends on the application.

Comment: So following on Gordon's comment, to better normalize your table, you might consider replacing the text values in the `jenis_tunjangan` column with a foreign key of some sort, which then points to another table maintaining the actual string values _without_ repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table 1` --`jenis_tunjangan_ID` should be foreign key relationship to Table 2 of column `ID`

```
id_tunjungan    jenis_tunjangan_ID   besar_tunjangan

BR001   01   250000
KAM001  02 100000
KAM002  03   80000
KR001   02 75000
KR002   03   75000
MT001   03   50000
MT002   01   200000
PA001   02 400000
PA002   03   150000
SA001   03   75000
```

Table 2 -- create primary key as ID which has jenis_tunjangan

```
ID    jenis_tunjangan
01    beras
02    jabatan
03    kesehatan
```

This will help you to solve redundancy you have in your current table for column `jenis_tunjangan`